# Adding class to child element by parent Element ID and Child Class

Tags: javascript, ajax

I think I got this wrong "$('#groupdepID01 > .lahatkami')" 
$('ID > Class')

script

```
 $('#groupdepID01 > .lahatkami').addClass('iamSelected');
```

html

```
<div id="groupdepID01">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="01" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID02">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="02" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID04">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="03" />
</div>
```

Expected Output should be

```
<div id="groupdepID01">
     <input class="lahatkami iamSelected" id="01" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID02">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="02" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID03">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="03" />
</div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery `addClass` line is actually executed?

Comment: i think your code are correct, maybe you have some error, check your dev tools, `console` if you see some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working.

I suspect you did not include **jquery**

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in you project..

Run Code And After Check `Developer tools` or press `F12`

**iamSelected** Class Add inside  id="groupdepID01"

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qz4pL6fh/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$('#groupdepID01 > .lahatkami').addClass('iamSelected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupdepID01">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="01" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID02">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="02" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID04">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="03" />
</div>
```

***For Testing Purpose Add Css In*** `iamSelected`

```js
$('#groupdepID01 > .lahatkami').addClass('iamSelected');
```

```css
.iamSelected
{
 background-color:blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupdepID01">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="01" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID02">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="02" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID04">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="03" />
</div>
```

***Using jquery-3.1.1.min.js***

```js
$('#groupdepID01 > .lahatkami').addClass('iamSelected');
```

```css
.iamSelected
{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupdepID01">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="01" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID02">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="02" />
</div>

<div id="groupdepID04">
     <input class="lahatkami" id="03" />
</div>
```

Comment: You only need the last snippet in my opinion

Comment: I am using "jquery-3.1.1.min.JS" and theres no error, I just thought that addClass is not working or $(#ParentElement_ID > .ChildElement_Class) doesn't work, should i changed the jquery plugin?

Comment: I've seen the class was added, Thanks @Sumit patel

Comment: i updated my answer  check it .use jquery-3.1.1.min.JS.

Comment: @Sumit patel, Thanks